# Custom font face doesn't load in web page

Tags: css

My file structure

- diary:

  - diary.html
  - css

    - diary.css
  - sources

    - fonts

      - EmblemaOne-Regular.woff

My css code is:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'EmblemaOne-Regular';
    src: url('../sources/fonts/EmblemaOne-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}

body {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: small;
}

h1, h2 {
color: #cc6600;
text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'EmblemaOne-Regular', sans-serif;
font-size: 220%;
}

h2 {
font-size: 130%;
font-weight: normal;
}

blockquote {
font-style: italic;
}
```

The problem is, that this font didnt apply to my h1 title? Can someone explain, why?
Btw I tried to remove quotes, use double quotes, remove "format", use full internet path. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you see the font being downloaded successfully in the network tab of developer tools when you load the page?

Comment: I'm not sure but is it because you're using single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/NtpHxner3HWkWm - there is screen of dev tools

Comment: i am so sorry, this font doesnt support my language letters. Sorry guys for wasting your time.